# RxAndroid, combining multiple web calls

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

```
public List<Office> getOffices(){

    final List<Office> offices = new ArrayList<>();

    Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            for(String[] of : backToArray(downloadWebPage("http://api.ataxcloudapp.com/v1/franchise/listing/?location=" + zip))) {
                offices.add(
                    new Office(
                        of,
                        backToArray(downloadWebPage("http://api.ataxcloudapp.com/v1/franchise/details/hours/" + of[0])).get(0),
                        downloadImage("https://www.ataxcloudapp.com/WebShared/uploads/franchises/" + of[0] + "/manager-photo.jpg?404=picture-placeholder.jpg"),
                        downloadImage("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + of[12] + ","+ of[13] +"&zoom=12&size=300x150&maptype=roadmap")
                    )
                );
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe();
    return offices;
}
```

The above solution kinda works, it takes very long to load results and its not consistent. the last 3 calls are all dependent on information given in the first call. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that in order to be able to compose async methods, they all should return `Observable<Something>` and not directly `Something`.

So you should change your download methods to

```
public Observable<Image> downloadImage(String url)
public Observable<WebPage> downloadWebPage(String url)
```

Or create wrapper methods around them if you cannot change them.

Then you can use `flatMap` and `zip` for the `getOffices` method:

```
public Observable<Office> getOffices() {
   return downloadWebPage("office-url")
      .flatMap(new Func1<WebPage, Observable<Office>>() {
         public Observable<Office> call(WebPage webPage) {
            String url1 = "blah" + webPage.getInfo1();
            String url2 = "blah" + webPage.getInfo2();
            String url3 = "blah" + webPage.getInfo3();
            return Observable.zip(
               downloadWebPage(url1),
               downloadImage(url2),
               downloadImage(url3),
               new Func3<WebPage, Image, Image, Office>() {
                  public Office call(WebPage p, Image img1, Image img2) {
                     return new Office(p.getInfo0(), img1, img2);
                  }
               });
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution. A couple extra notes... avoid `Observable.create` in general. There is (almost) always a way to compose what you need such as Samuel has done here, without the extra overhead of managing your own observable. For example, your custom Observable doesn't check for unsubscription. Also, if this is being used for displaying item lists, I would suggest using the observable to get the image URL strings, but not downloading them. Use something like glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide or Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ to manage loading images into views.